# Outbound Channel Adapter java configuration

Tags: spring-integration

Up to now, as far as I see, there is no annotation support for Outbound Channel Adapter.

```
<int:outbound-channel-adapter channel="channel" method="handle">
<beans:bean class="org.Foo"/>
```

One of the reasons for its absence could be functionality similar to the one provided by Service Activator.

It would be interesting to know, if there are plans to synchronize XML and Java configurations in the scope of Outbound Channel Adapter, as an explicit termination point of a processing pipeline?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, you can simply use `@ServiceActivator` on a method that returns `void`; we didn't feel a separate annotation was necessary for this case.